# Make HTML canvas bigger while scaling the website

Tags: javascript, browser, html5-canvas, scale

Do you have any idea how it could be possible not to scale a HTML canvas element while scaling the whole website (ctrl+"+" in most browsers) but to make its dimensions bigger? I have got an application where you can view large images, zoom and pan them in the canvas element. Now I think it would be cool to scale the website with ctrl+"+" to have more space for viewing the image. As it is by default the canvas scales, too and you gain nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use technique described in this article http://novemberborn.net/2007/12/javascriptpage-zoom-ff3-128.

The main idea is to place any two elements and set for the first element css value in pixels like top\left\width etc and for the second element percentage value. When you scale the page the percentage value stays unchanged, but the value in pixels changes depending on zoom factor.
Based on these changes you can calculate the scale factor and multiple it with canvas dimensions to scale it.

How to calculate scale factor you can find in the demo link from article in the script block.

Answer (score -2):

Something like Zoomooz.js could work - http://janne.aukia.com/zoomooz/

Comment: An answer should have more than just a link